# my script is reading only first .txt file which was first read by it

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have this script which takes one txt file with different links and a url. and this script checks the backlinks which are present on links that are in .txt file. my script is this

```
<?php
$needle = $_GET['utext'];
$file = $_GET['ufile'];
$source = file_get_contents($file);
$new = explode("\n",$source);
foreach ($new as $check){
    $a = file_get_contents(trim($check));
    if (strpos($a,$needle)){
        $found[] = $check;
    }
    else{
        $notfound[] = $check;
    }
}

echo "Matches that were found: \n ".implode("\n","\n".$found)."\n";
echo "<br> <br> <br> <br>";
echo "Matches that were not found \n". implode("\n","\n".$notfound);

?>
```

Comment: How can you possibly believe that posting something containing "enter code here" all over the place is acceptable? :/ Please... have a look at the editing help. There is a bright orange button for it right above the edit box.

Comment: I'm with @GBD, the actual question is missing. Also wrap parts into functions of it's own, that will allow you to make your code more speaking and will make it easier to deal with error conditions.

Comment: My script reads only first txt file. And this is my main problem. I want. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: what is your exact expected o/p ? paste `var_dump($new)` and `var_dump($source)` in your question

Comment: You want? What you want?

Comment: > "My script reads only first txt file" Because you have `$source = file_get_contents($file);` - it reads only 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

Add more debug output. printf/echo-debugging is not the sharpest spoon in the drawer but it get's you started.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$needle = $_GET['utext'];
$file = $_GET['ufile']; // that's ok regarding security?
$new = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$new = array_map('trim', $new);
echo '#entries: ', count($new), "\n";
$found = array(); $notfound=array();

foreach ( $new as $check ) {
    echo 'processing: ', $check;
    $a = file_get_contents($check);
    echo ', length: ', strlen($a);
    if (strpos($a,$needle)) {
        echo ", found\n";
        $found[] = $check;
    }
    else {
        echo ", not found\n";
        $notfound[] = $check;
    }
}

echo '#Matches: ', count($found), "\n";
echo '#No-Matches: ', count($notfound), "\n";
echo "Matches that were found:\n ", implode("\n", $found), "\n";
echo "Matches that were not found:\n", implode("\n", $notfound), "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks VolkerK, 
and I was just looking to correct my script. and u corrected me. Thanks again.